# NGINX server configuration for static apps

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a website which is an app containing other apps.
In the main app, I'll load the other apps with iframes.

The main app is served at the domain root: http://example.com
The other apps are served under the /apps path:

- http://example.com/apps/app-a
- http://example.com/apps/app-b

Also the apps are developed in Polymer so there is client side navigation. I make sure the /apps path is not used on the client side to hit the NGINX server correctly but it also means that for url such as http://example.com/view1 it should redirect to the index.html of the main app. And for url like http://example.com/apps/app-b/view1 it should redirect to the index.html of app-b.

I'm trying to configure NGINX to serve those static apps.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        root /var/www/example.com/main-app;
        index index.html;

        try_files $uri $uri/index.html /index.html;

        location ~ /apps/([a-z-]+) {
                alias /var/www/example.com/apps/$1;
        }
}
```

With the above config I have the main app working with the correct redirection to the index.html for the /view1 path for example.

But I have a 403 forbidden error for the sub apps.

> directory index of "/var/www/example.com/apps/app-b" is forbidden,
>   client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /apps/app-b/

I've tried other configurations with no success (infinite redirection leading to /index.html/index.html/index.html...).

I'm sure about the filesystem permissions all directories are 755 and files are 644.

I don't know why it is trying to do a directory index.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `alias` with a regular expression `location`, you need to build the entire path to the file. Currently, you are only capturing the second path element.

Having said that, you do not actually need to use an `alias` here, as the `root` directive can be use instead.

```
location /apps/ {
    root /var/www/example.com;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Comment: It was not working because the location /apps does not match the folder name on the file system. I have something like /var/www/example.com/other-apps. For now I changed the other-apps to make it work with what you proposed (which makes sense of course).